# Зацикливание while при вводе строки через prompt

Tags: javascript, while

Есть две переменные, в которые записываются данные:

```
let finance = +prompt('Ваш бюджет?');
while (finance === "" || isNaN(finance) || finance === null) {
    let finance = prompt('Ваш бюджет?');
}
let name = prompt('Название вашего магазина?');
while (name == "" || name == null) {
    let name = prompt('Название вашего магазина?');
}
```

При вводе в первую переменную все записывается без проблем. Во вторую тоже, но если при вводе во вторую переменную сначала нажать "Отмена" или "Ок" и потом ввести без ошибок, то она зацикливается и скрипт не идет дальше, хотя первая переменная работает нормально. В чем проблема?

Comment: Уберите `let` внутри цикла.

Comment: А можете объяснить почему в первой работает все окей а вот во второй переменной нужно убирать let?

Comment: @ДарханУрустимов 1. Код с `finance` у вас зацикливается ничуть не меньше по той же самой причине. 2. Вы `finance` приводите к числу сразу (с помощью унарного плюса), поэтому сравнения `finance === ""` и `finance === null` бессмысленны (при пустом вводе и отмене `finance` у вас равно `0`).

Comment: @Regent, Да, даже ответ начал писать про это, но потом переклинило что-то :)

Comment: @Grundy мне кажется, что это не дубликат. Здесь проблема не с `window.name`, а с областью видимости переменных.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, уже переоткрыл.

Answer (score 3):

#### Проблема в лишнем `let`.

Так как с использованием этого ключевого слова область видимости ограничена блоком, а не функцией - значение введенное внутри цикла никак не совпадает с тем, что проверяется в условии.

---

#### Почему не зацикливается в первом случае?

Так как используется унарный оператор `+` - результат `prompt` сразу приводится к числу.

Приведение к числу работает согласно [таблице](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-tonumber) в которой отмечено, что в случае `null` результатом будет `+0`, пустая строка, либо строка только из пробелов будет приведена к `0`.

Поэтому при нажатии отмены или вводе пустой строки ни одно из условий не выполняется.

Стоит отметить, что при вводе строки, которую невозможно привести к числу в первом случае так же будет зацикливание, так как результат приведения в этом случае будет `NaN`.

Comment: @Regent, Добавил